# session_status() returns PHP_SESSION_NONE when session created

Tags: php, session

I am facing a problem distinguishing a session state when no session exists and a state, when session is simply stopped, but not destroyed.

[1] Let's say I have not created a session yet. Session file does not exist, session variables do not exist. As I call function `session_status()`, it returns `PHP_SESSION_NONE`, great.

[2] Now I have created a session using `session_start()` and check for the session status again, now I get `PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE`, also great.

[3] Now I end session (without destroying it) using `session_write_close()` and check session status. Now I get `PHP_SESSION_NONE`! The thing is... this time session data (and all variables) exist!

How do I distinguish state [1] and state [3]? Function `session_status()` returns same result as if state is the same (and it is not the same).

Comment: Well if you close the session, it's no longer active, so I think the response makes sufficient sense. If there was another constant "PHP_SESSION_CLOSED" to distinguish between a session existing but being inactive, and a session not having even been created yet, then you'd expect it to return that. But no such distinction exists in the available values that session_status() can return, so the response you've got is the most accurate one available, IMHO

Comment: looks like XY problem, why do you need such distinction? maybe you just need to close session later, but use some variable inside of session object to determine whether it is new session or preexisting one?

Comment: My question back to you would be...why do you _need_ to be able to distinguish these states? What possible use case is there for it within your application? Why do you need to know how exactly the Session is being managed by PHP? Either you can access it or you can't...the rest of the details can be left under the hood.

Comment: The reason I need to distinguish is this: if session already created, I would like to access it. If it does not exist, I would like to rather not use sessions for now (and not create any)

Comment: probably you can check existence of session cookie in request, `session_name` can be used to get cookie name

Comment: Huh? That doesn't seem to make any sense. Only the PHP code can start a session, so the idea that you would avoid using it if it doesn't already exist is bizarre, I think. If a session exists, it will be because the PHP code in your application created it - so why try to avoid using something your own code has created?? And you shouldn't need to test that either, because as the developer you should have some idea whether sessions are used by the application already or not. Make up your mind whether your application is going to need to use Session data or not, and then stick to it.

Comment: Also, if you want to access the Session data when it exists, then presumably you have some purpose for accessing that data? What will the application do instead if there is no such data (other than simply create it for future use)?

Comment: Okay, I may not have perfect understanding of how sessions work. The idea is that I would like to not use sessions for as long as user has not logged-in. And only if user decides to log-in, only then I would like to create session file and run sessions

Comment: standard approach is to always start session, but use variable inside of it to detect whether user is logged or not

Comment: The trouble with that is that in order for your code to _know_ if the user is logged in or not, the code will - upon each request received by the server - need to access the session and check whether the specific session value indicating a valid login session exists ... at least that's the normal way people manage login validity in a web application: they set a session value when the user logs in, so that the system can check any future requests to see if the user is authorised or not. That will apply unless you're using a completely different mechanism such as token-based authentication

Comment: Also what is the reason for wanting to avoid using sessions during the logged-out time? Is using sessions giving you some specific problem that you're trying to avoid? It doesn't normally cause any noticeable performance overhead or anything like that, in 99.99% of cases.

Comment: Website may be visited by random people (and not people, meaning bots). In my head it makes more sense to not use sessions unless user decides to login. Maybe not the right approach, just thinking whether it's possible. If not, I may simply use sessions at all times

Comment: `Website may be visited by random people (and not people, meaning bots)`...yes, but what does that have to do with sessions? It's not clear what your specific concern is in regards to bots visiting your site, or how the use of sessions would relate to that.

Comment: When they login, set the variable `$_SESSION['username']`. Other code that needs to distinguish logged-in and non-logged-in can check whether this variable is set. Then they don't set any other session variables that are unneeded.

Answer (score -1):

From reading the comments, it seems that you would like to use sessions when a user logins, but would still like your site to be accessed by users that are not logged in. Essentially to do this, you would need to create an auth script, that checks the users login credentials and then starts a session. Make sure you always have the following code at the top of every page, to properly read the sessions:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Because you would then know if the user has logged in, because the session would be active, you do not need to use sessions for the non logged in users. You can simply create restricted areas with a simple if statement:

```
if(isset($_SESSION[‘username’])){
  //User is logged in
  //Execute code 
}
```

You can then add in an else to this if to handle users not logged in:

```
if(isset($_SESSION[‘username’])){
  //User is logged in
  //Execute code 
}else{
  //redirect non logged in user
  //change URL to destination URL
  header(‘Location: URL’);
}
```

Comment: Checking if the user is logged in still requires creating and accessing the Session though, even if nothing is stored in it. So it doesn't fulfil the OP's idea of never creating a session for users who aren't logged in.